# Sidemenu JQuery in Wacom's new site design

Tags: javascript, jquery, sidebar

http://www.wacom.com/
Does anyone know what JQuery does the new wacom site sidemenu uses? I'm working on a project and I want to implement ta same sidemenu effect where upon mouseover, the categories are eased in just enough to show the icons and then the submenu for that particular category is displayed alongside, just like how it has been implemented in wacom's site itself.

Comment: page source doesn't show them using jquery. sidebar appears to be mostly css driven.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion after I checked the source, but I'm a noob at Javascript and JQuery so I assumed I might have not been able to find it out. Thank you so much for replying back :)